# ElasticSearch: How do I fulltext-search a array field?

Tags: elasticsearch

Sample document in elasticsearch

```
{
    "name": "Tom",
    "hobbies": [
        {
            "hobby": "go for a walk"
        },
        {
            "hobby": "board games"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get all person who's hobby contains "walk" or "game(s)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array Field Index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#object-arrays) This reference will give you more clarity about the Array fields index process.

To enable the full text search in an array you need to specify the `path` foe the search `array fields` in your case the path is `hobbies.hobby`.

As you want to enable the search for `game` & `games` you need to specify the `stem` analyzer[`snowball`] to achieve the language search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify path to it

```
POST indexName/_search
{
  "query": {"terms": {
    "hobbies.hobby": [
      "walk",
      "games"
    ]
  }}
}
```